# Best way to make large clean cuts into particle board?

Tags: cabinets, saw, particle-board

Pictures:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP7F0.jpg   (please try to ignore the large amounts of dust/dog hair)

I have a fairly cheap tv cabinet / AV rack that I assume is made with particle board. It is sectioned of into spaces for stereo / AV equipment. In one of the spaces I have a very large power amplifier that is nearly too large to even fit. It runs very hot right now and does not get adequate ventilation.

What I want to do is cut two large square holes in the top, leaving room for the other small devices to still be supported and sit up there, a very large hole in the left side of the unit, and either cut a large hole in the right side divider piece, or just remove this divider entirely if it doesn't compromise the structural integrity.

How would I go about make good clean cut that don't look tacky? Is the right divider needed for support?

Thanks!

Comment: It is still going to look like a hack even with "clean" cuts,

Comment: What tools do you have available? Oscillating tool (ie, Fein)? Jigsaw? Drill with hole saws? Any way you slice it, you'll want to cover your cut edges with adhesive edge banding. And fwiw, I'd leave some of the upright divider; otherwise, your shelf will sag over time (and leave unsightly bits where the support was).

Comment: Removing that much material is likely to weaken the unit.  I'd try putting the power amp on the top shelf so it can use convection cooling as designed.

Comment: The previous recommendations are good & you should listen to them. I'm assuming the structural integrity is good (be sure!). So moving past that, start out with drawing your rectangles that you wish to cut with a pencil. Next, take a drill with a Spade Bit (http://www.harborfreight.com/steel-spade-drill-bit-set-13-pc-69028.html ) to drill large circular holes in the four corners (be sure to stay within your pencil lines). Next, take a Jig Saw (http://www.harborfreight.com/32-amp-variable-speed-jig-saw-62405.html ) to cut the long straight lines of your square. I'd leave corners rounded.